# Permanet adjustment of frame buffer's resolution

Tags: linux

I am trying to adjust the resolution of the frame buffer to **1024x600** using the following bash code

```
fbset -xres 1024
fbset -yres 600
fbset -vxres 1024
fbset -vyres 600
```

Everything is working fine, but when I reboot my pc, the resolution is reseted back to **1280x1024**

```
mode "1280x1024"
    geometry 1280 1024 1280 1024 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,8/24
endmode
```

How do I make the 1024x600 resolution permanent ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save fbset setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194864/how-to-save-fbset-setting)

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck